# syntax error in alter table partition by col in mysql

Tags: mysql, partitioning

i have below query

```
ALTER TABLE `logs`
ADD 
PARTITION BY RANGE (date)
(
PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (1515745595)
)
```

but mysql return this error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY RANGE (date)
>   (
>   PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (1515745595)
>   )' at line 3

Comment: What is the data type of date?

Comment: timestamp and int(11)

Comment: And what version

Comment: I will argue against using `PARTITIONing` without discussing the purpose.  Many uses provide no advantage.  More [_discussion_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that date is an int field that stores a timestamp. In which case there a couple of things wrong with your alter statement 1 you don't need and add clause 2) you need to cater for any values which fall outwith p1 so maybe something like this

```
ALTER TABLE `logs`
PARTITION BY RANGE (`date`)
(
PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (1516442053),
partition p2 values less than (maxvalue)
)
```

Also according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html *Beginning with MySQL 5.5.1, it is also possible to partition a table by RANGE based on the value of a TIMESTAMP column, using the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function, as shown in this example:* which you may wish to review.

Comment: A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

Comment: still have this

Comment: Only if you have a primary key I suspect.